# How to deal with duplicate file names when moving files in terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

So I'm trying to move images of a specific dimension to another folder. But working with a huge number of files, the same filename once and a while presents itself. And I have been using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
targetDir="$HOME/Documents/pixx"

find "$targetDir" -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.jpeg' 2>/dev/null | \
while read -r filename; do
    hw="$(sips -g pixelHeight -g pixelWidth "$filename" 2>/dev/null)"
    h="$(awk '/pixelHeight/{print $2}'<<<"$hw")"
    w="$(awk '/pixelWidth/{print $2}'<<<"$hw")"
    if [[ $h -eq 270 ]] && [[ $w -eq 360 ]]; then
        mv "$filename" "$targetDir/hehe"
    fi
done
```

I found out that `mv` had a backup command `mv --backup=t` but that is just for linux, so I can't use that. But it would be great to have some sort of equal function in this script above.

So how can I add a incremental number if the same filename appears?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already a [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) user, you could install [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) and get quick access to GNU mv. This is installed as `gmv` so that it doesn't break any scripts that rely on BSD mv's syntax.

If you don't use homebrew and do not want to install it, you'll need to do tests with `[ -f ${filename} ]` etc. (which I expect is what you wanted).

Once you have homebrew installed, run,

`brew install fileutils`

Then you can `gmv --backup=t` as you wished to.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't that difficult to do. You need to test if the file exists in the target directory then add an increment to the file name and test if that name exists.

Replace `mv "$filename" "$targetDir/hehe"` in your code with:

```
base=$filename##*/}     # same as using basename but
                        # with parameter expansion

if [ -e "${targetDir}/hehe/${base}" ]
then
    echo "File exists; $base needs to be renamed.."
    i=1                 # initialize the counter
    shortname=${base%.*} # file name without extension
    ext=${base##*.}     # the file extension

    while [ -e "${targetDir}/hehe/${shortname}_{$i}.${ext}" ]
    do
        ((i++))
    done

    echo mv -- "$filename" "${targetDir}/hehe/${shortname}_{$i}.${ext}"

else
    echo "$base does not need renaming..."
    echo mv -- "$filename" "$targetDir/hehe" 
fi
```

This code will only echo the `mv` statements and will not rename any files. Please test thoroughly. If you are confident that output will give you the desired results then remove the echo in front of the `mv` statements.